# Why changing xdebug.profiler_output_name has no effect?

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I am trying to change the `xdebug.profiler_output_name` setting in my php.ini, but it seems to have no effect at all. The weird part is that if I change any other value in php.ini, and even `xdebug.trace_output_name`, then they are changed (I can see it with `phpinfo()`).

I assume something is overwriting the `xdebug.profiler_output_name` value after php.ini gets loaded. Are there any obvious places where I should look?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, because of an invalid comment above the line in the INI file which was stopping the parser from reading any further. (I'd used a # not a ;)

I discovered it by scrolling a little further back to the top when inspecting the options.

```
# php -i | grep xd
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini on line 11
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini,
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
...
```

Otherwise to look for where the settings might be overridden, search for "ini" in the settings:

```
# php -i | grep ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-bcmath.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
...
```